# Single login to SSH, share the session to run git-receive-pack and remotely run some other commands

Tags: java, git, bash, ssh

With only one login to SSH (to reduce login time),
How do I run some other commands and as well as pushing git repository in the middle?

e.g.
login to remote via SSH

1. remote: `cd abc`
2. remote: `git init`
3. local: `git push` --> Question: How can I substitute with remote commands directly so I can use the same SSH session? How do I use `git-receive-pack`? Because a `git push` creates another dedicated SSH session.
4. remote: `git checkout branch_abc`

Note: I can write a program to use SSH in java to control everything between 2 and 4, so the answer is not limited to bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/speed-multiple-ssh-connections-same-server) for information on setting up a shared master SSH connection to speed up multiple sessions.